# how to configure messages property for validation using annotations spring

Tags: java, spring, annotations, spring-data-rest

I am using spring-data-rest and I need to configure messages.properties using annotations, What I have done in my configuration class is,

```
@Bean public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource(){
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource reloadableResourceBundleMessageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    reloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.setBasename("messages");
    return reloadableResourceBundleMessageSource;
}
```

and tries to access the property in my **messages.property** file,

```
notnull.empty=rr is required.
```

as,

```
ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(arg1, "rr", "notnull.empty", "test is required.");
```

in my Validation Class. But the default message only received and if I remove default message null is received. Is it possible to configure validation messages property file through annotation? Am new to springs, so I cant bet it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to change de value of the parameter in `reloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.setBasename("messages");` and use a the proper path, similar to this one `reloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.setBasename("/WEB-INF/messages/messages");`

Comment: Thank you Fran. Actually no WEB-INF folder in my project. I have placed like this and worked, ****reloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.setBasename("classpath:/message");**. And if we keep in classpath means it cant be reloadable or what? Whether I have to consider relocating properties file?

Comment: I created a proper answer below. Please vote it if it was helpful for you. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that it is not able to find the message file.  It is needed to provide the correct location path to the `setBasename` method.  You can do it in several ways, I will show you two:

1.Using a path from the project root like:

```
    reloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.setBasename("/WEB-INF/messages/messages")‌​;
```

2.Using a path within the classpath, like:

```
    reloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.setBasename("classpath:/messages/messages")‌​;
```

I prefer the first because servers use to cache files loaded from the classpath and it makes more difficult to catch changes in the message files.